# How to disable "Window animation scale" programmatically on Android 4.0+ devices?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I'm using a **Service** that displays a view using `WindowManager`, and animation occurs every time I change the view's size using

```
windowManagerLayoutParams.height = newHeight;
((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).updateViewLayout(mMainLayout, windowManagerLayoutParams);
```

If I disable manually the scale animations, no animation occurs.
Scale animation disabled manually like so:
http://www.cultofandroid.com/11143/android-4-0-tip-how-to-find-and-disable-animations-for-a-snappier-experience/

**Is there a way to disable the window scale animations for my application programmatically?**

Comment: Could you provide a short video to show what exactly you mean? There are layout animations and there are activity animations and there are dozens of different other animations out there :D

Comment: It's like a slide animation. The type of the animation doesn't really matter, I just want to disable it.

Comment: and the answer depends not on the animation itself but for what events the animation is triggered. If it is for an activity transition, the answer is different than for a pure layout animation...

Comment: It's not an activity animation, as there are no activities involved.

Answer (score 16):

I just had this same problem while working on a system overlay in the SystemUI package and decided to dig through the source to see if I could find a solution.  [WindowManager.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html) has some hidden goodies that can solve this problem.  The trick is to use the privateFlags member of [WindowManager.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html) like so:

```
windowManagerLayoutParams.privateFlags |= 0x00000040;
```

If you look at line 1019 of [WindowManager.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/WindowManager.java) you'll see that 0x00000040 is the value for PRIVATE_FLAG_NO_MOVE_ANIMATION.  For me this did stop window animations from occurring on my view when I change the size via [updateViewLayout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewManager.html#updateViewLayout%28android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29)

I had the advantage of working on a system package so I am able to access privateFlags directly in my code but you are going to need to use reflection if you want to access this field.

Comment: Android added this flag only in 4.3, so the animations still occur to me on other devices.

Comment: @RonTesler What is name this flag? Please, add link from android api.I didn't fount flag in this class [WindowManager.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: The flag is PRIVATE_FLAG_NO_MOVE_ANIMATION, but as I stated in my answer, this is not a public API so there is no link for it other than looking in the source code for WindowManager.

Answer (score 8):

As @clark stated this can be changed using reflection:

```
private void disableAnimations() {
    try {
        int currentFlags = (Integer) mLayoutParams.getClass().getField("privateFlags").get(mLayoutParams);
        mLayoutParams.getClass().getField("privateFlags").set(mLayoutParams, currentFlags|0x00000040);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //do nothing. Probably using other version of android
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try `Activity#overridePendingTransition(0, 0)`?

Check out [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29):

> Call immediately after one of the flavors of startActivity(Intent) or finish() to specify an explicit transition animation to perform next.

Comment: Yes I did. It's not an activity animation, as there are no activities involved.

Comment: If you have a UI, my guess is that you should have an activity.

Comment: That's not always the case.  You can attach views as panels/overlays via the WindowManager which sounds like what he is doing..

Comment: I agree. I didn't say that it wasn't possible to have a UI without activities, I just advised that he shouldn't do it without, because the cases where it's actually acceptable are really rare.

Comment: @BenoitDuffez the main reason for these type of “hacks” is (nowadays at least) for testing purposes. Espresso tests for the most part.