# how to move a view via windowManager.UpdateViewLayout without any animation?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-windowmanager

When i do :

```
    LayoutParams lp = getLayoutParams(view);
    lp.x = absoluteX;
    lp.y = absoluteY;
    this.mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(view, lp);
```

Then i have one linear animation from the position where the view is to the new position absoluteX/absoluteY. how to move the view without any animation ?

I try to set **lp.windowAnimations = 0** but it's change nothing :( 
any idea how i can do ?

If it's not possible to avoid the animation, is their any way to know the actual position of the view? maybe i can make it invisible still the real position is not absoluteX/absoluteY

**NOTE:**

looking the source code of android, i saw in the file WindowManager.java this entry :

```
     /**
     * Never animate position changes of the window.
     *
     * {@hide} */
    public static final int PRIVATE_FLAG_NO_MOVE_ANIMATION = 0x00000040;

    /**
     * Control flags that are private to the platform.
     * @hide
     */
    public int privateFlags;
```

it's look like to be what i need, but i don't know how to access and set such flag :( any idea ?

Comment: You could probably `removeView()`, then immediately add it back with the updated `LayoutParams`.

Comment: Mike M, effectivelly doing RemoveView and AddView remove the animation, but is this really the best way to do? i look in the android source code and i see that layout params have PRIVATE_FLAG_NO_MOVE_ANIMATION and also public int privateFlags; maybe i must play with this ?

Comment: We solved this by following this answer. Use reflection to disable the private flag animation. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33171254/5053013

Comment: @MikeM. thanks, that solved problem for me!

Comment: As for solution by @Kevin Marlow, there's still a flicker left even after disabling animation flag

Comment: did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @RafaelLima no sorry, or I forget how I did :(

Answer (score 1):

try to disable the layout animation:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13777628)

Comment: He is asking about moving a view without animation, and this attribute disable the animation resulting from layout changes as far as i know.

Comment: thanks jamal but unfortunatly it's didn't work :( i try to set it like this   <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"> 
    <item name="android:animateLayoutChanges">false</item>
  </style>

Answer (score 1):

```
val lp = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    width, 
    height, 
    this.windowManagerType(),
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
    or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
    or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
    or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
    or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
    PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT
)

val className = "android.view.WindowManager\$LayoutParams"
try {
    val layoutParamsClass = Class.forName(className)
    val privateFlags = layoutParamsClass.getField("privateFlags")
    val noAnim = layoutParamsClass.getField("PRIVATE_FLAG_NO_MOVE_ANIMATION")

    var privateFlagsValue = privateFlags.getInt(lp)
    val noAnimFlag = noAnim.getInt(lp)
    privateFlagsValue = privateFlagsValue or noAnimFlag
    privateFlags.setInt(lp, privateFlagsValue)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.e("EXCEPT", "EXCEPTION: ${e.localizedMessage}")
}
```

Comment: I've be tearing my hair out over this weird animation issues thinking it was an issue with layout passes, or my own animation logic. Absolutely excellent find